Updated portable Eclipse issues in PyDev interactive console
I updated my portable Eclipse version from 2022-06 to 2024-06 and now for some reason when running Python code in Debug mode and stopping at a breaking point the following happens:
If I want to run multiple lines in the interactive console e.g.
print(
 „print this text“
 )

Then my Python 3.10 interpreter will give me a Syntax error for not closing the first bracket (after print). This doesn’t happen with Python 3.8:
File "<console>", line 1
  print(
SyntaxError: '(' was never closed

Important to know here is, that with the older Eclipse version there was no issue with any of the interpreters.
Do you have any hints for me on how Eclipse might have changed, if it is an issue with the PyDev plugin or any indication why the old version works with both but the new one has this issue?
Thanks a lot, any help is appreciated!
Best
Leo
